# Nativescript-Vue: Gradle could not extract native JNI library

Tags: android-studio, gradle, nativescript-vue

I am trying to learn Nativescript-Vue and I followed all the instructions on how to get started. After a little while, I was able to create my first project but I coudn't run it into the emulator.

I just want to know why Gradle could not extract native JNI library everytime I run `$ tns run android --bundle`.

I already have my environment setup properly. I run `$ tns doctor` and there are no issues. I installed Android Studio so I could use its emulator.

Specifically, I get something like this:

---

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not extract native JNI library.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit
>     code 1.

---

Why did this happen? How to fix this error?